# Magento 2 remove validation dynamically

Tags: magento2, form-validation

Hi I have a custom form where in I display configurable products with its options. The form is given validation using:

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' data-form="quick-view-form" data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl($bundle->getId()) ?>" name="bundlediscount-option" id="bundle_product_addtocart_form_custom" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="bundle_product_addtocart_form">
```

The code for validation is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $('#bundle_product_addtocart_form_custom').mage('validation', {});
    });
</script>
```

The configurable options appear just like it normally does like:

```
<div class="product-options-wrapper" id="product-options-wrapper">
<div class="fieldset" tabindex="0">

        <div class="field configurable required configurable-container-2045">
        <label class="label" for="attribute93">
            <span>Color</span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="super_attribute[2045][93]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute93" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">



            <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="58">Black</option><option value="65">Orange</option><option value="68">White</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="field configurable required configurable-container-2045">
        <label class="label" for="attribute145">
            <span>Size</span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="super_attribute[2045][145]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute145" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true" disabled="">
                <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>


            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a checkbox and on uncheck I need to remove validation for a particular field. Basically need to toggle validation on checkbox click.

Please help!

Comment: you want to remove validation for a particular field or whole form?

Comment: @Piyush for a particular field.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('#attribute145').data('metadata').validate.required = false
```

will remove required validation from the field.
By setting required to true will set the validation again `jQuery('#attribute145').data('metadata').validate.required = true`

Answer (score 0):

Anjith's answer is correct.

But if you don't have 'metadata' data, add this line before:

`jQuery('#attribute145').metadata();`

Comment: You can add this as a comment to complement the @anjith one instead of adding a new answer